# Is this idiomatically modified version of “battle of wits” fine?

Tags: idioms

I’m wondering whether this word-played version of *battle of wits* in the sentence, **”They both duelled in an exchange of wits”**, acceptable or just plain nonsense.

Comment: Having exchanged wits, they would have each other's wits. That is not a battle, it is a trade. Yes, it's nonsense.

Comment: @NigelJ Oh, okay. Although, according to Apple Dictionary, the word exchange can also refer to “a short conversation or argument.”

Comment: Yes, an 'exchange' is an exchange of views, which might be a confrontational exercise. But you would not exchange 'brains' only thoughts.

Comment: @NigelJ Let’s say we substitute “exchange” with its synonym “argument” (as said by Apple Dictionary). Does “They both duelled in an argument of wits” still hold as being nonsense?

Comment: When we have an idiomatic expression 'battle of wits' why not stay with it ? 'An argument of', to me, means that was the subject about which they were arguing.

Comment: @NigelJ Hi, I just researched about the use of “argument of wits”. It seems to be that there are a lot who have used it in a way that would be similar to “battle of wits”. Also, they don’t seem to be using it to mean about which they are arguing. Allow me to show you one excerpt I found: “After a verbal argument of wits, they decided that it would be fair to offer the city something.”

Comment: Presumably, you're basing this on an expression like "exchange of gunfire".  So you could use "an exchange of insults" or "an exchange of repartee", which are parallel to "an exchange of gunfire". But "an exchange of wits" would be like "they dueled in an exchange of guns", which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Seems fine, but the "both" sounds superfluous to me. It takes two to duel, so "they duelled in an exchange of wits" would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I’m wondering whether this word-played version of [battle of wits](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/battle+of+wits)
>   in the sentence, ”They both dueled in an exchange of wits”, acceptable
>   or just plain nonsense?

idiom defined:

> A competition in which opponents attempt to gain victory or an
>   advantage over each other using their intelligence.

and

> If a competition or disagreement is a battle of wits, each person
>   involved in it uses their intelligence to beat their opponents.

It's acceptable as **you have abandoned the idiom**. There is no need to hold it as the touchstone. You created a grammatically acceptable phrase to suit your needs.  Placed in context in your writings it should work and be acceptable.